# how to extend the limit of RecursionLimit in C# asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

in ASP.NET MVC i got the exception RecursionLimit exceeded when i try to sent the data to browser through JSON.

how i can make it work no matter how much big JSON is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default value of the `RecursionLimit` property is 100, which means that it can serialise objects that are nested to a depth of 100 objects referencing each other.

I can't imagine that you actually have objects that are nested that deep, so the most likely reason for the error message is that you have an object that contains a reference to itself, or two objects that have references to each other. As that causes an infinite chain of child objects, you get the equivalent of a stack overflow in the serialiser.

Comment: It is not that hard to imagine, I'm trying to serialize a simple 54 levels deep tree structure, to build a diagram in the client-side using JavaScript, and it fails because the recursion limit is too small :(

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena: You can increase the recursion limit, but you should consider if there is a different way that you can represent the data.

Answer (score 4):

Use view models to break the recursion. You cannot JSON serialize objects that are recursively referencing themselves. Ayende Rahien has a nice [series of blog posts](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/04/10/refactoring-toward-frictionless-amp-odorless-code-the-case-for-the.aspx) about this issue.

Comment: what do you means view models. can you show some code. i really not understand what you want to say

Comment: @Steven Spielberg, a view model is a class that you define and which will contain only the properties that are necessary for a given view. So instead of sending your actual model which might contain hundredths of unnecessary properties and circular references you will write a simple class which will be mapped from this model and sent to the view as argument to the Json method.

Answer (score 1):

You can JSON Serialize objects that are recursively referencing themselves as you Ignore those Properties. My Users Class has a Property that also is a User Object, but I ignore that Property doing:

```
    Users oSuperior;
    [ScriptIgnore(), XmlIgnore()]
    public Users Superior
    {
        get
        {

            if (oSuperior == null)
            {
                oSuperior = new Users();

                if (iIDUserSuperior > 0)
                    oSuperior.Load(iIDUserSuperior);
            }
            return oSuperior;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Microsoft has added some helpful properties to the [JsonResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) for increasing the recursion limit and maximum JSON length in the **.NET framework 4.5**:

```
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    var result = Json(obj);
    result.RecursionLimit = 1024;
    result.MaxJsonLength = 8388608;
    return result;
}
```

Hence, now you can easily set how "big" you want to allow your JSON objects to be by setting those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since the following configuration seems to be useless in ASP.NET MVC:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization recursionLimit="1024"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I ended up using the following one liner to solve my problem:

```
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(){RecursionLimit = 1024}.Serialize(@Model)
```

Instead of using MVC's serialization method which has a default recursion limit of 100:

```
Json.Encode(@Model)
```

It may not be the best solution, but it sure is simple to use in case you need a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Besides aforementioned methods, you can replace the default JSON serialization with that provided by Json.NET which [by default does not seem to have an explicit limit](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_MaxDepth.htm):

> A null value means there is no maximum. The default value is null.

E.g.:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theObject);
```

**NOTE:** ASP.NET Web API uses this [JSON serializer by default](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization?one=2).